# How to get the type of an object in string?

Tags: python

I would like to get the type of an python object in string, not in class. Is there another way than the long :

```
var_type = type(variale)
if var_type == str:
    return "str"
if var_type == int:
    return "int"
       .
       .
       .
```

Comment: What do you mean by but in string, not in class?

Comment: @fractal397 I want the type of an object in str type, to put it in a string after.

Comment: var_type.__name__

Comment: Just replace "==" with "is" in your function and it should do the trick for you

Comment: @David You can put in answer if you want, its working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = 10
var_type = type(b)
print(var_type.__name__)
int
```

`var_type.__name __` will return the type of the variable as string